# Use Ant project as Gradle subproject

Tags: java, git, gradle, ant

In a project I'm working on, I'd like to add another library. The problem is that I'm using Gradle and the library I want to use isn't on Maven, it's only available as a git repo with an Ant build setup. I was thinking of adding it as a submodule, and then using Gradle's [Ant support](https://docs.gradle.org/current/userguide/ant.html) to build the library and then depend on it, but I can't figure out how to have Gradle reference the build output of the library. Would I have to use `compile files(...)` or is there a better way?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'd build the JAR file for that library in Ant and then check it in with your project source code. You can then reference the file via the following:

```
dependencies {
    compile files('libs/ant-lib.jar')
}
```

Alternatively, I could upload the file to an in-house binary repository if you use one and then reference it via its coordinates.

Comment: This is what I'm doing now, but I was wondering if there was a way to have the ant project as a subproject so that everything could be built with a single command.

Comment: Yes, you could do that. However, I think it's pointless to rebuild the library artifact if you are not actually changing the code. What you could do here is that you set up a new subproject in your multi-project build and create a project dependency on it. In the new subproject you'd [import the Ant build](https://docs.gradle.org/current/userguide/ant.html#sec:import_ant_build).